# Is :$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1-e^n}=0.5\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-e^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

$$S_1=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{1-e^n}=-0.11\cdots \text{ and }\ S_2=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-e^n}=-0.23\cdots$$ on Wolfram Alpha: ([first sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+((-1)%5En%2F(1-+e%5En)),+n%3D2+to+infty) and [second sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+((1)%5En%2F(1-+e%5En)),+n%3D2+to+infty)).

I'm unable to show if I'm true that $S_1=0.5 S_2$ because I can't come up to the closed form of both $S_1$ and $S_2$

Comment: It's not true.$~$

Comment: Already the third decimal is off. VTC.

Comment: $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{n}}{1-{{\rm e}^{n}}}
}=- 0.117813191108066723072504189378
$ and $1/2\,\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \left( 1-{{\rm e}^{n}} \right) ^{-1}=-
 0.119141402336545199437678879500
$

Comment: What is true is that $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{1-e^n} = - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{2n} + e^{n}}$$ while
$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1-e^n} = - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{2n} - e^n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Mathematica can be found closed form solution:

$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{1-\exp (n)}=\ln (-1+e)+\psi _e(-i \pi )-\frac{1}{-1+e}+i \pi$$

$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{1}{1-\exp (n)}=-1-\frac{1}{1-e}+\ln (-1+e)+\psi _{\frac{1}{e}}(1)$$

where: $\psi _{\frac{1}{e}}(1)$ and $\psi _e(-i \pi )$ is   [q-digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html)

**EDITED:**

Alternative to WolframAlfa to calculate numerically sum.

Go to [SymPy web page](http://live.sympy.org) and paste code:`Sum(1/(1-exp(n)), (n, 2, oo)).evalf(50)`

and click `Evaluate Button`.

[image]